# WPF window fails to initialize from Revit ExternalCommand

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, revit-api

I'm making a Revit addin that will open a WPF window to interact with a user. I followed the modeless dialog example in the SDK. I made my program following MVVM pattern. However, debugging the program kept throwing exception at the ExternalCommand step: **"object reference not set to an instance of an object"** the ExternalCommand class is as below:

```
[Autodesk.Revit.Attributes.Transaction(Autodesk.Revit.Attributes.TransactionMode.Manual)]
class RevitCommand : IExternalCommand
{        
    public virtual Result Execute(ExternalCommandData commandData, ref string message, ElementSet elements)
    {
        try
        {
            ThisApplication.thisApp.ShowWindow(commandData.Application);

            return Result.Succeeded;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            message = ex.Message;
            return Result.Failed;
        }
    }
}
```

While the ExternalApplication class is:

```
    public class ThisApplication : IExternalApplication
{
    //Class instance
    internal static ThisApplication thisApp;

    //Modeless instance
    private MainWindow m_MainWindow;

    public Result OnShutdown(UIControlledApplication application)
    {
        if (m_MainWindow != null && m_MainWindow.IsVisible)
        {
            m_MainWindow.Dispose();
        }
        return Result.Succeeded;
    }

    public Result OnStartup(UIControlledApplication application)
    {
        m_MainWindow = null;   // no dialog needed yet; the command will bring it
        thisApp = this;  // static access to this application instance
        return Result.Succeeded;
    }

    public void ShowWindow(UIApplication uiapp)
    {
        // If we do not have a dialog yet, create and show it
        if (m_MainWindow == null )
        {
            RequestHandler handler = new RequestHandler();
            ExternalEvent exEvent = ExternalEvent.Create(handler);
            MyViewModel vmod = new MyViewModel(exEvent,handler);
            m_MainWindow = new MainWindow();                
            m_MainWindow.DataContext = vmod;
            m_MainWindow.Show();
        }
    }

}
```

I'm suspecting the exception was thrown since `thisApp` is null, but the example in the SDK works fine. The only differences are that they used a WinForm instead of WPF and ExternalEvent is passed into the view instead of the view model.

Comment: What line does the exception stack trace show the exception originated from?

Comment: I'm guessing that `ThisApplication.thisApp` is null - are you sure your `ThisApplication.OnStartup` method is being invoked *before* your `RevitCommand.Execute` method?

Comment: Yes, 'ThisApplication.OnStartup' was never invoked, the 'ExternalCommand' throw exception right away.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

turn out my suspicion is correct, `thisApp` being null really made Revit throw the exception, to fix it I initiate a new `thisApplication` class instance then call the `ShowWindow` method. and it does what I expected.

```
public virtual Result Execute(ExternalCommandData commandData, ref string message, ElementSet elements)
    {
        try
        {
            new ThisApplication().ShowWindow(commandData.Application);

            return Result.Succeeded;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            message = ex.Message;
            return Result.Failed;
        }
    }
```

Thank you @Dai, for your suggestion.